# How to save new image dimensions after scaling during upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-resizing

**QUESTION EDITED**

Below is a simple **script to allow users upload pictures**. Once the upload is done, the pictures are displayed as a *170px(h) x 150px(w) thumbnail.*

Most of the pictures look **distorted once resized**, so **I guess I need to scale them too**.

I'm stuck at saving the new image dimensions. **See TODO.**

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

    $maxWidth  = 150;
    $maxHeight = 170;

    $name = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'];
    $type = $_FILES ["image"] ["type"];
    $size = $_FILES ["image"] ["size"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name']; 
    list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($tmp_name);



  if ($originalWidth > $maxWidth || $originalHeight > $maxHeight)
  {
      if ($originalWidth / $maxWidth > $originalHeight / $maxHeight) 
      {
       // width is the limiting factor
       $width = $maxWidth;
       $height = floor($width * $originalHeight / $originalWidth);
      } else { 
        // height is the limiting factor
        $height = $maxHeight;
        $width = floor($height * $originalWidth / $originalHeight);
  }


   // Resample 
   $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($maxwidth, $maxheight);
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
   imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $maxwidth, $maxheight,  
   $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

    TODO: how do I save the new dimensions to $location ?

//start upload process
$RandomNumber = uniqid();
$location = "uploads/$RandomNumber";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);   
query("UPDATE users SET profilepic = '".$location."' WHERE id = '$id'"); 


}
?>
```

Some of my code is inspired from this question:

[Distorted image resize with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165386/distorted-image-resize-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for you question: "How can I get the initial dimensions of the picture the user wants to upload?"

From the manual:

**list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");**

With that in mind, you may be able to replace the file path in the above example with $_FILES["image"] to get the dimensions data.

Once you have the original dimensions, you can adjust the image to be smaller while preserving the original aspect ratio.

For error checking, you would probably want to either check that there is only one file in $_FILES["image"], or loop through an array in the event you allow for multiple image uploads using the same name for each image's HTML input tag.

Comment: +1 . I've just edited my question so that my issue is easier to understand, please have a look at the TODO. Maybe you can help.

Comment: When you say "how do I save the new dimensions to $location?" are you asking how you save the new, resized image to $location? If so, I believe you should use the PHP function imagejpeg like so:

`imagejpeg($image_p, $location)`.

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom class that helps me do this in projects. Feel free to use my code:
https://gist.github.com/695Multimedia/7117003